# Chamar um Modal via Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio

Eu tenho uma tela que faz a troca de senha do usuário. Essa tela mostra o nome do usuário e ao clicar no nome, ele é direcionado para a tela para trocar senha.

Como eu faria para fazer essa chamada com um modal, eu ja tenho os scripts, mas não consigo usa com o Html.ActionLink

@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "ChangePassword", "Manage" ))
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });   
            $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
                $('#myModalContent1').load(this.href, function () {
                    $('#myModalLogin').modal({
                        /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                        keyboard: true
                    }, 'show');
                    bindForm(this);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

        function bindForm(dialog) {
            $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.success) {
                            $('#myModalLogin').modal('hide');
                            $('#replacetarget').load(result.url); // Carrega o resultado HTML para a div demarcada
                        } else {
                            $('#myModalContent1').html(result);
                            bindForm(dialog);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
    </script>

<div id="myModalLogin" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="myModalContent1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu te recomendo chamar uma Action no seu controller através de um método .js onde ela vai retornar a sua View() com seu model:

```js
public ActionResult RetornarModal()
{
  return PartialView("_Partial", model);
}
```

E no sucesso da requisição você continua fazendo do mesmo jeito, alimentando o `.html()` com o resultado da requisição.

Defina o evento do `onClick()` do link pro seu novo método fazendo a requisição.